# File Reading Class C++

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, ifstream

I am making a file reading class. It should, when constructed open the file with the given string and depending on which constructor is called use the second string supplied to skip through the file to the line after the string given.

Here is my code as it stands:

```
SnakeFileReader::SnakeFileReader(string filePath)
{
    fileToRead_.open(filePath.c_str(), ios::in);
}
SnakeFileReader::SnakeFileReader(string filePath, string startString)
{
    fileToRead_.open(filePath.c_str(), ios::in);

    string toFind;

    while (toFind != startString  && !fileToRead_.eof())
    {
        fileToRead_ >> toFind;
    }
}
string SnakeFileReader::ReadLine()
{
    string fileLine;

    if (!fileToRead_.fail() && !fileToRead_.eof())
        fileToRead_ >> fileLine;

    return fileLine;
}
int SnakeFileReader::ReadInt()
{
    string fileLine = "";

    if (!fileToRead_.fail() && !fileToRead_.eof())
        fileToRead_ >> fileLine;

    int ret;

    istringstream(fileLine) >> ret;

    return ret;
}
SnakeFileReader::~SnakeFileReader()
{
    fileToRead_.close();
}
```

The problem I have is that in the second constructor I get a segmentation fault. I get another segmentation fault in the read line function as soon as I declare a string.

[Edit] Here is the extra code requested. I am making a "Snake Game" as a part of the first year of my degree. I want the game to read and save files rather than hard code variable values. I will finally be using this class a lot to setup a level in the game. However here are a few lines that should demonstrate how i intend to use this class:

```
//Level.cpp
std::string fileToRead = "resources/files/level1.txt";
SnakeFileReader sfr(fileToRead);
std::string mapFilePath = sfr.ReadLine();
ImageFile(mapFilePath).load(map_layout);
mapWidth_ = sfr.ReadInt();
mapHeight_ = sfr.ReadInt();
level_cell_size_ = sfr.ReadInt();

map_ = new TileData*[mapWidth_];

for (int i = 0; i < mapWidth_; i++)
{
    map_[i] = new TileData[mapHeight_];
}
```

Layout of the file:

```
resources/images/Map1_Layout.bmp
40
30
20
```

Class declaration:

```
#ifndef SNAKE_FILE_READER_HPP
#define SNAKE_FILE_READER_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
class SnakeFileReader
{
    public:
        SnakeFileReader(string filePath);
        SnakeFileReader(string filePath, string startString);
        ~SnakeFileReader();
        string ReadLine();
        int ReadInt();
    private:
        ifstream fileToRead_;
};
#endif // SNAKE_FILE_READER_HPP
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are constructing it, and the place that you call `ReadLine` on it?

Comment: Please try to produce a small, **complete** program that is causing this problem.

Comment: I suspect that you are compiling without warnings enabled.  Is that the case?

Comment: I updated the question with the information you wanted

Comment: He's *clearly* talking to you, @Xymostech...  :)

Comment: @Drew i do have some warnings but not from this part of my code, the warnings are regarding non static data member initialisation

Comment: @DavidKimbrey `sfr.~SnakeFileReader();` is a Really Bad Idea.

Comment: @DavidKimbrey seriously. In case you took Drew's comment with a grain of salt. It is a *really* bad idea to do that. delete that line of code. Also, you may do well to know that the not-so-2D array you're mimicking with your TileData pointer array is odd. You're setting it up in column-major order, not row-major order.  The major index (the rows) should be the *height* magnitude, while the minor index (the columns) should be the *width* magnitude. You may be doing the opposite on purpose, but I'm kinda doubting it.

Comment: Okay I had a feeling it was a bad idea to invoke the destructor manually. I did want to set my array up like that, the map represents a grid so the map_[x][y] needs to be in the right place for when I render the level. Do you have any idea why I am getting the segmentation fault?

Comment: Not sure why but after restarting my computer it now works... Not sure why. Question, if I left out the destructor and ran the program would it close the file after i stopped it running? Would having the file open in another program (notepad++) effect the ability to read the data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your constructor, but the problem with ReadLine() is that you're trying to return the memory address of an automatic variable, which is destroyed when you exit the function.

The simplest fix would be to remove the '&' on the return value, and just return a string. But if you're determined to return a memory address, try this instead:

```
string *SnakeFileReader::ReadLine()
{   
string *fileLine = new string;

if (!fileToRead_.fail() && !fileToRead_.eof())
    fileToRead_ >> *fileLine;

return fileLine;
}
```

This will dynamically allocate the string and pass back the pointer. The difference is that dynamic variables are not automatically destroyed when you leave their scope. The string will still exist on the heap until you delete it yourself (which you must remember to do when you're done with it).

Comment: Pointer management is good at tripping up new programmers.  Why not just return a `string`?

Comment: Good point. I assumed he wanted to return an address, but it's more likely that was a mistake and he really just wants a string. Edited to include that.

Comment: The code in the question is **not** returning an address.  The `&` in that context makes it a `string` *reference*.

Comment: Hi - I changed it to just using normal strings - still get the error, the segmentation fault was before the function returned anyway

Comment: @DavidKimbrey is it possible for you to post the decl of the SnakeFileReader in the question as well? Thanks. (sidenote: put your fileReader member in an initializer list).

Answer (score 0):

in the ReadLine function, you return a reference to a variable allocated on the functions stack. you are corrupting the stack, crazy things can happen. your compiler should have warned you about that.

Comment: sfr.~SnakeFileReader(); !!! destructors get called automatically when an object goes out of scope. you should never call it manually.